# Ola's Maintenance Solution Plan script newer version

Tags: maintenance-plans

We have very old version of Ola's Maintenance Solution Plan script implemented in our many servers and wondering if i have to update to his latest scriptm how can i upgrade easily on all my servers?

Thank you!

Comment: First I'd check on Ola's site to see if there any any changes that you need. If there's nothing you need then no need to upgrade. In terms of deploying to all your servers - the same way you'd make any other change that you want to make to all servers at once. If you don't have an existing mechanism for that, I'd suggest you check out dbatools or SQL CMS - https://dbatools.io/ https://matthewmcgiffen.com/2018/04/10/cms-effortlessly-run-queries-against-multiple-sql-servers-at-once/

Comment: Thank, We will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

> how can i upgrade easily on all my servers?

You should use dbatools - [`Install-DbaMaintenanceSolution`](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Install-DbaMaintenanceSolution)

> This script will download and install the latest version of SQL Server Maintenance Solution created by Ola Hallengren

Alternatively, Ola's solution is on [github](https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution)

Comment: Thanks Kin.
I have downloaded the new script but i believe that I can just run the new script on each server and it will replace the newer version (recreating), only i need to change the sql agent job parameter - SET @CreateJobs = 'N'. Implementing into all the servers same time, how?

Comment: Yes .. you take that script, modify it as per your needs and deploy it across all the servers. Do it incrementally - dev ..... PROD.

Comment: It's not clear from the document, but the powershell command takes a list of instances. You could also use the [server groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/register-servers/create-or-edit-a-server-group-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver15) feature, which can execute a command against multiple servers.

Comment: Thanks Kin, I will check it out and test it out before moving to production.